# Do the English have an ancient (obsolete) verb for the action of the book opening?

Tags: verbs, history, translation

Do the English have an ancient (obsolete) verb for the action of the book opening?

For example, in Russian we say otkrit' (open the book), but in the Old slavonic the verb razognuti (to unbend the book) was used.

Comment: I guess you'd know better than me, since I don't know Russian at all, but [this web page](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/russian-english/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C) seems to be saying that Russian **открыть** just corresponds to English **open**. The *specific* implication of *to open **a book*** seems to be just a matter of context, not inherent to the verb itself. I seriously doubt English has a dedicated term for opening ***books*** as opposed to things like cans of beans or doors.

Comment: "Crack" is occasionally used in this sense.

Comment: @HotLicks: Eh? Can you give an example utterance where ***to crack*** means ***to open a book***, without the actual object being explicitly specified?

Comment: One usage very specific to (used) books is *I do have a copy of that book, but it's **well-thumbed***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - That doesn't mean that you've ever opened the book.  You inherited it from your grandmother and haven't touched it since.

Comment: @HotLicks: It doesn't necessarily mean I personally have opened the book (many times, or even *once*). Just that it's been opened many times by *someone*. (Or maybe it's just been opened a few times by someone with dirty hands! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - So it has nothing to do with Opie's question.

Comment: It's not obsolete, but the American Heritage dictionary lists 'to crack a book' as an idiom since the 1930s, 'crack' in the sense of opening being from the early 1700s.

Comment: @HotLicks: Of course it's relevant. ***Thumbed*** (and especially ***well-thumbed***) is a verb form very specifically associated with books having been (frequently) opened. Verbs like ***open*** and ***crack*** have no particular relationship to ***books*** outside of specific contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "The *action* of the book opening".  "Thumbed", in the adjective sense, refers to the *state* of the book.

Comment: (And, interestingly enough, "crack" refers to the sound the *spine* makes when the book is opened.)

Comment: If someone said to me *I cracked a good murder mystery novel last night*, my default assumption would be that they had ***solved*** the mystery in the book, rather than that they had simply opened the book (for the first time, and/or breaking the spine?).

Comment: I've also heard/read "heel" used to refer to the spine of a book occasionally, and I think possibly "keel" once or twice.

Comment: In Russian the verb razognuti (to unbend) is also used with the noun knee. Which verb is used in English with this noun?

Comment: is seeking an obsolete English word not off topic?

Comment: @lbf if so, then what ever can be on topic?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the English"*? The [English people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_people) or the [English language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language)?

Comment: @PeterMortenson when a nationality/adjective is preceded by the definite article it becomes a collective noun, e.g. the French (people), the Germans, the poor (people), the sick etc.

Comment: when i hear "opening a book" I think of gambling

Comment: @lbf: No, it isn't; see [this question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5260/8019). You might also consider the "archaic" tag, for just such questions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. There may not be an old word in English that does what you describe, but it is important to note that the English word "open" relative to a book meant something different in earlier times.

To open a book now usually means to part or spread the cover and the pages into a position so you can read the pages contained in the book.

However, books used to be made by folding sheets of paper larger than the page size and they would be sold without trimming the edges, so when you got your new book, it would be "unopened" meaning that you couldn't turn the pages. You had to "open" the book with a dull knife (like a letter opener) by ripping along the folds. (This is why some books have ragged edges of the text block, to evoke the memory of those ripped page edges.)

The OED has

> e. transitive. To cut open the leaves of (a book) when they have been left joined along an edge during the making; to cut open (the leaves) of such a book.

You will find old books described (by knowledgable book dealers) as "unopened". This correctly means that the folded sheets are un-ripped; it doesn't mean that no-one has ever spread the covers and looked inside.

Comment: If you want to avoid the ambiguity of _unopened_, you can call a book whose sheets have not been trimmed _intonso_ instead, which is unambiguous.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Unambiguous? All I can find from a search of "intonso" are Italian translations.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet This is the first reference to book I found in my searches "si dice di libro con le pagine non ancora tagliate, come un tempo erano i libri nuovi; nuovo, intatto", obviously meaning in Italian what you just said.

Comment: books are still made from sheets larger than a page, I;ve encountered some with defects leading to two pages being joined by a paper bridge.

Comment: @Jasen I purchased a volume of English poetry printed in the 1870's from a rare book dealer around 2005 and it *still* had some joined pages.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet: "Uncut" is the more common term for books with uncut pages.  Indeed, I had never seen "unopened" used in this context before.

Comment: There's a scene in The Great Gatsby (the book at least) where a houseguest is raving about Gatsby's commitment to cosplaying rich, where he points out that all the books in Gatsby's library are real books. However, the fact that they are also all still uncut was taken as proof that Gatsby "knows where to stop."

Comment: Ohh, I was just thinking about this word today, "intonso", and it reminded me of the similarly derived "tonsure" (that monks sometimes have). I guess someone with intact hair might be "un-tonsured" or "in-tonsured".

Answer (score 23):

Until 1960, possibly later, Gallimard sold books unbound and uncut. 'Uncut' meant that the pages were still in their signatures with the outer edge of most pages presenting a folded edge. Before you read the book you had to 'cut the pages.' This was also the case in England 1820: even bound volumes had to have their pages cut.

There's an obscure joke, possibly Samuel Johnson, where a nouveau riche says "These books, they are my friends." To which the other replies, "I see you don't cut your friends." (Cutting your friend is to ignore them deliberately) Sorry, that's absurdly complicated. But 'Cut the pages,' or simply 'to cut,' is certainly an outdated word for opening a book.

**Update:**
The Shorter Oxford under 'paper' has **-knife**

> **[paper]-knife,** a knife of ivory, wood, etc., used *esp.* to cut open the leaves of an uncut book.

Comment: @D Mac It is always a mixed pleasure to find someone agrees with you but has posted an answer while you were chasing a reference.

Comment: Yeah, but you don't get points for being first. :-)

By the way, are you referring to Gallimard the French book publisher?

Comment: In book parlance, "uncut" is different from "unopened". You can cut open a book, but cutting is more strictly used to mean trim (usually in a guillotine). It leaves a smooth edge on the text block and make it unnecessary to "open" the book as a result. There's a joke about "keeping the deckles", but I bet you know that one. :-)

Comment: _Fascicle_ isn’t the word you’re looking for here: a fascicle is a separately bound and published part of a larger work, usually intended to be rebound together with (or otherwise combined with) the remaining fascicles of the same work. What you’re talking about here is simply a _sheet_.

Answer (score 13):

The Middle English verb *[undon](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED48470/track?counter=1&search_id=1096856)* was often applied to opening a book (and many other objects).

> c1300 SLeg.Fran.(1) (LdMisc 108)159 : He **on-dude þe bok** and þe furste þat he cam to Þat was a godspel. (He undid the book and the first that he came to - that was a gospel.)
>
> a1325 SLeg.(Corp-C 145)354/166 : He…wende him sulf forþ is wei & þe oþer **vndude þe bok**.  (He walked himself forth his way and the other undid the book.)
>
> c1475 Mankind (Folg V.a.354)797 : All þe **bokys** in þe worlde, yf þei **hade be wndon**, Kowde not a cownselde ws bett. (All the books in the world, if they had been undone, could not have counseled us better.)

This meaning has since disappeared along with the book clasps that would have once been common on books. (To see a few examples of bindings, see "[Medieval bindings](https://www.bl.uk/medieval-english-french-manuscripts/articles/medieval-bindings)" on the British Library site.)

Comment: +1. This is simply the older conjugation of **undo**, of course, and today we would undo the clasps of a book or the wrapping, rather than the book itself.

Comment: Kudos for finding citations that use the word in this exact sense.

Comment: Interestingly, the German standard word for opening a book is *aufschlagen* (literally, "to beat open") and it originates from forcefully opening such clasps (though todays speakers are unaware of that)

Answer (score 7):

One obsolete [Middle English word](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/43737/43737-h/43737-h.htm) for “open” is **unschette** (the opposite of modern *shut*), and a word that’s changed meaning and once meant *opened* is **unlokynne** (modern *unlocked*).

An old-fashioned word for reading a book that modern readers would still understand might be **leaf** through it.